# How to get the Parent Item of the SelectedItem on ListView.SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Does anybody know how I can retrieve the selected `Ellipse` "bgColor" from the following code please?
I can retrieve the `Color`, but I need to get the `Ellipse` which holds it.

XAML

```
            <ListView Name="BgColorList" Height="80" Width="850"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ColorList}"
            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewTransparent}"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
            ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled="True" 
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            SelectionChanged="BgColorList_SelectionChanged"
            Margin="0,0,0,35">
                    <ListView.DataContext>
                        <local2:NamedColors />
                    </ListView.DataContext>
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <ItemsWrapGrid />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="65" Width="65">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse Name="bgColor" Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Width="50" Margin="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="Transparent" StrokeThickness="1">
                                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding }" />
                                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                                </Ellipse>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                </ListView>
```

C# - I don't seem to be able to find a way to retrieve the Ellipse here.

```
    private void BgColorList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListView view = (ListView)sender;
        var selected = view.SelectedItem;
        Color selectedColor = (Color)view.SelectedItem;
    }
```

Comment: Hi did you tried Tap event of Ellipse !

Answer (score 1):

The `ListView` has a `ContainerFromItem` methid which should give you a reference to the `ListViewItem` container. You could then get a reference to the `Ellipse` using the `VisualTreeHelper` class:

```
private void BgColorList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListView view = (ListView)sender;
    var selected = view.SelectedItem;
    var container = view.ContainerFromItem(selected);
    if (container != null)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = FindVisualChild<Ellipse>(container);
        if (ellipse != null)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}

private static T FindVisualChild<T>(DependencyObject obj) where T : DependencyObject
{
    for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
    {
        DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);
        if (child != null && child is T)
            return (T)child;
        else
        {
            T childOfChild = FindVisualChild<T>(child);
            if (childOfChild != null)
                return childOfChild;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution could work for my needs, but container returns null?

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the Parent Item of the SelectedItem on ListView.SelectionChanged

For `ListView`, you could use [`ContainerFromItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem) method to get `ListViewItem` for `SelectedItem`, then use [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper) to find the child element, but `VisualTreeHelper` will consume system performance. And for you scenario, the better way is listen Ellipse Tapped event as @Noorul said, when the item is clicked the Tapped even will invoke.

```
private void BgColor_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var ellipse = sender as Ellipse;
}
```

Comment: *`VisualTreeHelper` will consume system performance*? What API won't "consume" the system? Or what do you mean. That it is slow to find an `Ellipse` in a `Grid` with just two children?

Comment: @mm8, your answer is correct, and I voted up your answer.  but VisualTreeHelper  used reflection method internal and we do not recommend use it.